# Parse query equalto PFUser Object

Tags: parse-platform, swift2

This is what I have pulled from the PFUser:

```
let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
        currentUser!.refreshInBackgroundWithBlock { (object, error) -> Void in
            print("Refreshed")
            currentUser!.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock { (result, error) -> Void in

              let userSchool = currentUser!.objectForKey("school") as! String
```

And then I want to use the "userSchool" in a Query for Participants.

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Participant")
        query.whereKey("school", equalTo:userSchool)
       query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
           (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            }
```

How do I get the `equalTo`: to signify "userschool" so I can then pull the data?
This is all on the same table too, BTW.

Comment: What is the behavior you're experiencing right now? The query looks correct if you're trying to query for all `Participant` objects which have `school` equal to the current user's `school`. Also, I'm not sure I can see the purpose of calling `refreshInBackgroundWithBlock` or `fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock` on the current user. That would only be needed if there is a chance for the user to be modified by other people or cloud code such that the local cache would get out of sync.

Comment: the call for user is working correctly, i cant print out the school name. my problem is im getting a "Use of unresolved identifier 'userSchool' " error on the query wherekey("school", equalto:userSchool) line

Comment: Gotcha. Sounds like it should be a simple syntax fix. Please update your code to show the complete sample. As it stands right now, I'm unsure of the connection between the two code snippets

Comment: I got rid of the 2 lines you told me too, It seems to be working,.